# Qmake INSTALLS variable - create symbolic link to directory

Tags: qmake

I am trying to add an INSTALLS rule to my qmake .pro file that will create a symlink in the build directory to the config directory in my project. Here's how I've tried to do it using the 'extra' member:

```
config.path = $$top_builddir/
config.files = $$rootdir/config
config.extra = ln -sf $$config.files $$config.path
INSTALLS += config
```

where top_builddir and rootdir are of course the paths to the build directory and root project dir, respectively.

The generated Makefile rule is:

```
install_config: FORCE
@test -d $(INSTALL_ROOT)/home/greg/Desktop/mg_builds/MPI-Debug || mkdir -p $(INSTALL_ROOT)/home/greg/Desktop/mg_builds/MPI-Debug
ln -sf /home/greg/Desktop/mg/config /home/greg/Desktop/mg_builds/MPI-Debug/
-$(INSTALL_DIR) /home/greg/Desktop/mg/config $(INSTALL_ROOT)/home/greg/Desktop/mg_builds/MPI-Debug/
```

The extra command has been added but there is also the command to `cp` the directory too which is causing causing the error:

```
cp: '/home/greg/Desktop/mg/config' and '/home/greg/Desktop/mg_builds/MPI-Debug/config' are the same file
Makefile:580: recipe for target 'install_config' failed
```

How can I suppress this or tell qmake to make a symlink rather than a copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little experimenting I found this works quite nicely. You can leave the `.files` member empty (i.e. `.files =`) or just omit it entirely and no copy command will be generated in the Makefile. The target directory can be written directly in the `extra` command. However, a `.path` is still required for the rule to be generated.

```
config.path = $$top_builddir/
config.extra = ln -sf $$rootdir/config $$config.path
INSTALLS += config
```

Makefile:

```
install_config: FORCE
@test -d $(INSTALL_ROOT)/home/greg/Desktop/mg_builds/MPI-Debug/ || mkdir -p $(INSTALL_ROOT)/home/greg/Desktop/mg_builds/MPI-Debug/
ln -sf /home/greg/Desktop/mg/config /home/greg/Desktop/mg_builds/MPI-Debug/
```